# How to determine the following inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Let $\boldsymbol{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, $n>2$ be a real vector such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i=0$. How to prove that
\begin{equation}
\left\lVert \sum_{i=1}^{n} \boldsymbol{n}_i x_i\right\rVert^2<\left\lVert  \boldsymbol{x}\right\rVert^2,
\end{equation}
where $\boldsymbol{n}_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$ are unit vectors such that $\langle \boldsymbol{n}_i,\boldsymbol{n}_j\rangle>0$, $i\neq j$

Comment: Does that mean $n_i\in\{-1,1\}$ (each $n_i$ has a magnitude of $1$) or $\sum n_i^2=1$?

Comment: @Andrei I think they're vectors of norm $1$ (due to the term "unit vectors" and the fact they're in bold).

Comment: Thanks @BrunoB. I did not notice the bold font

Answer (score 2):

If $n=2$ $$\|x_1\vec{n_1}-x_1\vec{n_2}\|^2=2x_1^2(1-\langle\vec{n_1},\vec{n_2}\rangle )\leq 2x_1^2$$ is false if $\langle\vec{n_1},\vec{n_2}\rangle <0.$

Comment: while if $n>2$?

Comment: $x_2=x_3=\ldots=x_n=-\frac{x_1}{n-1}$, $\vec{n_2}=\vec{n_3}=\ldots=\vec{n_n}$, $\langle \vec{n_1},\vec{n_2}\rangle=0$ seems to be a counterexample when one adds the further hypothesis $\langle \vec{n_i},\vec{n_j}\rangle\geq 0.$

Comment: If we consider the case $\langle \boldsymbol{n}_i,\boldsymbol{n}_j\rangle>0$, $i\neq j$?

Comment: Just make epsilon modifications to the above counter example to  fill your requirement of strictly positive scalar products.